# groupby.sum() sparse matrix in pandas or scipy: looking for performance

Tags: performance, numpy, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have the following dataset `df`:

```
import numpy.random
import pandas

cat = pandas.Series(numpy.random.random_integers(0,400,1000000))
ids = pandas.Series(numpy.random.random_integers(0,10000,1000000))
team = pandas.Series(numpy.random.random_integers(0,1,1000000))
df = pandas.concat([ids,cat,team],axis=1)
df.columns = ['ids','cat','team']
```

Note that there is only 400 distinct categories in the `cat` column. Conseqently, I want to prepare the dataset for a machine learning classification, i.e., create one column for each distinct category value from 0 to 400, and for each row, write 1 if the id has the corresponding category, and 0 otherwise. My goal is then to make a groupby `ids`, and sum the 1 for every category column, as follows:

```
df2 = pandas.get_dummies(df['cat'], sparse=True)
df2['ids'] = df['ids']
df3 = df2.groupby('ids').sum()
```

My problem is that the `groupby.sum()` is very very long, far too long (more than 30 mins). So I need a different strategy to make my calculation. Here is a second attempt.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy

text_encoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(dtype=numpy.int)
X = text_encoder.fit_transform(df.drop(['team','ids'],axis=1).values).astype(int)
```

But then, `X` is a sparse scipy matrix. Here I have two choices: either a find a way to `groupby.sum()` efficiently on this sparse scipy matrix, or I convert it to a real numpy matrix with `.toarray()` as follows:

```
X = X.toarray()
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(X)
df2['ids'] = df['ids']
df3 = df2.groupby('ids').sum()
```

The problem now is that a lot of memory is lost due to the `.toarray()`. And the `groupby.sum()` surely takes a lot of memory.

So my question is: is there a smart way to solve my problem using SPARSE MATRIX with EFFICIENT TIME for the `groupby.sum()`?

Comment: Is is just an example? My version of pandas must be old so I can't add the sparse argument when creating df2 with get_dummies(). But then `df3 = df2.groupby('ids').sum()` is very quick, although it takes indeed quite a lot of memory (c. 6Go). If groupby is slow with a sparse_matrix.. a solution may be to avoid it by sorting data on ids, finding where each id starts and stops, and then just .sum(0) on slices of the sparse matrix

Comment: Just to expand a bit, sorting would be `df.sort('ids', inplace = True)` and `df.groupby('ids').size()` would tell you how many rows to slice for each successive `id` in your sparse matrix. The slicing should work in a classical way e.g. `X[0:95,:].sum(0)` if there are 95 rows i.e. caracteristics for the first id.

Comment: Have you studied the pandas sparse docs? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/sparse.html

Comment: yes but to be honnest, the sparse pandas matrix do not work very well. First the groupby looks totally unoptimized, and there are bugs with print and other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: In fact this is a job for pivot_table(), so once your `df` is created:

```
df_final = df.pivot_table(cols='cat', rows='ids', aggfunc='count')
df_final.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

For the record but useless: following my comments on the question:

```
import numpy.random
import pandas
from sklearn import preprocessing

cat = pandas.Series(numpy.random.random_integers(0,400,1000000))
ids = pandas.Series(numpy.random.random_integers(0,10000,1000000))
team = pandas.Series(numpy.random.random_integers(0,1,1000000))
df = pandas.concat([ids,cat,team],axis=1)
df.columns = ['ids','cat','team']

df.sort('ids', inplace = True)

text_encoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(dtype=numpy.int)
X = text_encoder.fit_transform(df.drop(['team','ids'],axis=1).values).astype(int)

se_size = df.groupby('ids').size()

ls_rows = []
row_ind = 0
for name, nb_lines in se_size.iteritems():
  ls_rows.append(X[row_ind : row_ind + nb_lines,:].sum(0).tolist()[0])
  row_ind += nb_lines
df_final = pandas.DataFrame(ls_rows,
                            index = se_size.index,
                            columns = text_encoder.active_features_)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nevertheless, the matrix you obtain does not look as a get_dummies one (the index should be df['ids'].unique(), and the columns should be one per distinct cat values. Furthermore, you don't do the .sum(), so I am not sure this answer is good.

Comment: Finally, iterate over a groupby is usually very slow. I tried your code with `df_final.loc[cat, name] += 1` and it takes too much time.

Comment: I edited the code so that you get ids as rows and categories as columns. It does not use sum() because I use a different logic. I create the final dataframe with 0s and populate it: with `name`, I iterate over ids and for each id/name: instruction `df_final.loc[cat, name] = 1` writes 1 for categories relevant to this id in the column dedicated to this id. Finally I just transpose the dataframe to get ids as rows and categories as columns. It runs in a few seconds on my computer while it's not that recent.

Comment: But you need to sum(). If id 7 has 3 times the category 6, it's important that df_final[7,6] = 3, you understand?

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. For some reason I was thinking that categories were caracteristics of each `id` and had to be 0 or 1. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Can you delete your answer please so my question goes back to the "unanswered"?

Comment: Please have a look at my new answer. I tested it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: thank you, this looks fine, even if it feels a bit strange as a framework !

Comment: Indeed it felt strange.. I updated my answer.. the solution is actually essentially a one liner.